# How to configure more than one output directories for maven war plugin?

Tags: java, maven

I have configured the follwoing maven war plugin, but I created only one output directory:

```
     <plugin>
         <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>              
             <configuration> 
                <outputDirectory>C:\EclipseWorkspace\my_path\myPath2</outputDirectory>
              </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>default-war</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>war</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
      </plugin>
```

How can I configure this pligin to create two output directories for example?

Answer (score 7):

First, I highly recommend that you not override the output directory to be something other than "target/...".  Maven follows conventions, and while you can configure it away from conventions, it does mean that you will have to configure *everything* away from the conventional locations.

Now, if you want to duplicate work, you simply add a second execution.  To do so, you will need two different execution ids.

```
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-war</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>war</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>additional-war</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>war</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
```

And to have them have different configurations, add the configuration differences local to the execution.

```
       <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-war</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>war</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              ... stuff specific to the first war ...
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>additional-war</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>war</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              ... stuff specific to the second war ...
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
```

Note that this will not really create two output directories for a single war file, but rather it will repackage the war twice to two different output directories.  It's a fine detail, but occasionally it can be important.

Comment: Thanks ! Could you explan me, how I can configure the maven target path for the default-war? How I must be setup the directory path here?

Comment: @MaikHansen Maven is "convention over configuration" which roughly means that if you don't bother to specify something, it comes out in the place where everything else is expecting it.  With that in mind, I'd have one of your executions operate without a special configuration, and perhaps have the second one operate with whatever you determine to override.  Perhaps it would be better to solve the problem in a different way, but given the context in this question, it's hard to make any commentary as how that better way might exist.