# How to copy war file to multiple folders?

Tags: java, maven

It's possible to change the target build path where the `war` file is placed on `mvn package` by:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>my\target\folder</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Question: how can I create the war file in the default `/target`, folder, but additionally copy the war file to one (or multiple) other destinations after build?

Comment: What is the intention to do this?

Comment: @khmarbaise having the file locally on dev, and if test and ok directly deploy the war to production. which is mostly the case, thus handy if the war file is automatically copied in a parent folder of the production webserver.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple way to do that would be to bind an execution of the [`maven-antrun-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/index.html) to the `package` phase. The advantage is that you don't need to re-execute the `maven-war-plugin` like [mentioned in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25638223/1743880).

This execution would copy the main artifact to the folder `/path/to/folder`.

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.8</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <configuration>
        <target>
          <copy file="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war"
                todir="/path/to/folder" />
        </target>
      </configuration>
      <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

(This snippet must be placed inside the `<build><plugins>` element).

Running `mvn clean install` (or "Run As... > Maven Install" in Eclipse), Maven will do what you want. `${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war` refers to the main WAR artifact present in the build directory (which is `target` by default).